# Python3 ValueError: too many values to unpack with for loop

Tags: python-3.x

I've seen this same question asked around, but it's always with something like:

```
val1, val2 = input("Enter 2 numbers")
```

My problem is different.

I have two strings, `str1` and `str2`. I want to compare them byte-by-byte such that the output would look something like this:

```
str1  str2
 0A    0A
 20    20
 41    41
 42    42
 43    43
 31    31
 32    32
 33    33
 2E    21
```

So, I've tried various syntaxes to compare them, but it always ends in the same error. Here's one of my latest attempts:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
for c1, c2 in (tuple("\n ABC123."), tuple("\n ABC123!")):
    print("%02X    %02X" % (ord(c1), ord(c2)))
```

And the error:

```
$ python3 test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Of course, this line:

```
for c1, c2 in (tuple("\n ABC123."), tuple("\n ABC123!")):
```

has gone through many different iterations:

```
for c1, c2 in "asdf", "asdf"
for c1, c2 in list("asdf"), list("asdf")
for c1, c2 in tuple("asdf"), tuple("asdf")
for c1, c2 in (tuple("asdf"), tuple("asdf"))
for (c1, c2) in (tuple("asdf"), tuple("asdf"))
```

All of which threw the same error.

I don't think I quite understand python's zipping/unzipping syntax, and I'm just about ready to resort hacking a low-level solution together.

Any ideas?

Comment: I should mention that the utility for this is that one of the strings is internal and the other comes from a file. Even though they read the same, they are not matching, so I'm anticipating that it has extra control characters like `0A` at the end, and that's what I was trying to find out when I ran into this error.

Comment: Update: [I knew it!](http://pastebin.com/8YQk1uME) Python is including the `0A` from the end of the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I ended up doing this:

```
for char in zip(s1,s2):
    print("%02X    %02X" % ( ord(char[0]), ord(char[1]) ))
```

However, I notice that if I happen to have two lists of differing lengths, the longer list seems to get truncated at the end. For example:

```
s1 = "\n ABC123."
s2 = "\n ABC123!."
0A    0A
20    20
41    41
42    42
43    43
31    31
32    32
33    33
2E    21
#     !! <-- There is no "2E"
```

So I guess I could work around that by printing the `len()` for each string, and then padding the shorter one to meet the longer one.